# GetName for enum with duplicate values

Tags: c#

If I have duplicate values in a C# enum, saying

```
enum MyE {
  value1 = 1,
  value2 = 2,
  valued = 1
}
```

What should be the values of the following strings?

```
MyE N = (MyE)1;
string V1 = N.ToString();
string V2 = GetName(MyE, 1);
```

Is it true that V1 and V2 must contain the same values?
What these values should be?

I haven't found anything in MSDN or here concerning such a «dereferencing» of enums with duplicates, point me to a link, please, if I missed that.

Comment: If this is important for your application, this might help: `Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<string>().Select(s => Tuple.Create(s, Enum.Parse<EnumType>(s))).GroupBy(t => t.Item2).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList());`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Experimentation shows that:

> V1 = "value1"

and

> V2 = "value1"

However, this isn't guaranteed. The [MSDN page on `Enum.GetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) states:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result, when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your application code should never depend on the method returning a particular member's name.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.
BTW, for my real enum both GetName and explicit cast return the name of the second suitable enum member.

Answer (score 2):

From the "Remarks" section on the `Enum.GetName` method documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx), it says:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result, when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your application code should never depend on the method returning a particular member's name.

I ran a test to see what would happen experimentally, and it always returned the first value defined (in your example, value1), but according to the official documentation above, you *cannot rely on that* (see comment by @gluk47, indicating different behavior in the wild).

Comment: According to my experience, we cannot rely, MSDN is right)
My VS is 2008, I got the second value occurence from the enum. I guessed, the name selection was based on its lexicographical number among other enum members names, but after some tests it seemed that's not true either.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with other answers statements

> ... this isn't guaranteed ...
>
> ... you *cannot rely* on that ...

as well as with msdn statement:

> ... your application code should never depend on the method returning a particular member's name ...

### The story

There was an enum in my software

```
enum Blabla { A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3 }
```

at some point `A` value changes to `AA` and later `AA` changes to `AAA`. To keep backward compatibility I had to do

```
enum Blabla { A = 0, AA = 0, AAA = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3 }
```

This allows to deserialize old enum value (made by older versions of software) as `AAA`.

Then there was a report which prints `Blabla` setting value. And at some point every customer using new version start telling me what instead of `AAA` they see `AA` value. All of them see `AA` (and no one report seeing `A`).

What I did? I simply change the order (until result was `AAA`)

```
enum Blabla { AAA = 0, A = 0, AA = 0, ...}
```

and made a test to ensure what `Blabla.AAA` will be output as `AAA`. Problem solved?

### The proof

Looking at sources of `Enum.ToString()` (or `Enum.GetName()`), it uses [GetEnumName()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,1e2b5f2a6fdbbc66,references), which calls `Array.BinarySearch()` for sorted array of values to find an index of value.

The result of binary search is *deterministic*: providing it with the **same parameters** will return **same result**.

So:

- if you don't change enum, then result will be the same.
- it is possible to find result experimentally (or perhaps by understanding how [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works and how enum will be processed).
- there is no easy rule to determine result (e.g. you can't say "it always return first defined value").
- it's unlikely what `enum` format will be changed (e.g. order of definition and order of list of values differs) or `Enum.ToString()` will be changed, it can happens however, so make sure you have tests for cases where you rely on return value.

Comment: In this case, «this isn't guaranteed» means, that if your customer has a newer/older version of the .Net framework that is still able to run your application, they can get another name for an enum value. The algorithm is for sure deterministic in the same setup, but the behaviour is not fixed by some standard and can easily change over time and the framework versions. You should write your application in a way that nothing will be broken by that change — that's what means «not guaranteed» and «cannot rely».

Comment: But I see your point) Indeed, the functions from the original question should return the same value…

Answer (score 0):

Well, because there are no guarantees about the order and obsolete attribute seems to have no impact on `Enum` methods, I would usually suggest to use a string property for serialization purpose and use custom code to handle obsolete values.

That way, the primary `Enum` has no duplicate and contains only current values.

Depending on the serialization framework, you might be able to mark the string property as serializable but obsolete and the actual property used in code to be ignored by serialization.

To handle obsolete values in the string property setter, you can either use an `[Obsolete] enum` or a switch statement. Typically, I would probably use the former if I have a lot of obsolete values to handle and the latter if I have only a few values to handle.

Also it might make sense to put the code in an helper class or an extension method particularly if you load or store that value from a bunch of places.

Although I have not tried it much in production code, I am wondering if it would be better to use a `struct` instead of an `enum` to have more control... but I think it need a lot of boilerplate code that cannot easily be made generic.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this might be a little late to the Party, this may not be the greatest idea, however, the one work around I did find in my case in which I've had to use duplicate enums is to use the following from the question here; [Get String Name from Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433909/get-string-name-from-enum-in-c-sharp)

```
var name = nameof(DeclaredEnum.EnumName);
```

Resulting in:

```
EnumName
```

You can read more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) as to how it actually works.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about a way to recover an `Enum` name for a given (unknown) numeric value programatically at runtime; the method you present only pertains for static values in the compiler.